# Eclipse localization flags pt_rPT errors

Tags: android, eclipse, localization

Some wired things happens with my Eclipse. If I name values folders for localization like this: values-es, values-fr,... everything is OK, but if I want rename it to values-pt_rPT or values-pt_PT there is this error:

```
invalid resource directory name: C:....\res values-pt_rPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use "_" instead of "-": `values-pt-rPT`